# Access to file denied in C# .NET 3.1 forms

Tags: c#

Hello I was writing a basic text editor in C# on visual studio windows form using the .NET framework 3.1 long term support version everything worked fine until I wrote the save file script

Here's the code for "Form1.cs" which is where the open and save file functions reside

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Text_Editor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string locsave;

        private void openbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
            if (principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Run as Admin");
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread();
            }
            else
            {

                OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();

                if (openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    var locationArray = openfile.FileName;
                    string location = "";

                    locsave = locationArray;

                    foreach (char peice in locationArray)
                    {
                        location = location + peice;
                    }

                    var contentArray = File.ReadAllText(location);
                    string content = "";
                    label4.Text = location;

                    foreach (char peice in contentArray)
                    {
                        content = content + peice;
                    }

                    richTextBox1.Text = content;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }

        private void savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (@label4.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Open a text file first");
            }
            else
            {
                StreamWriter outputfile = new StreamWriter(locsave);
                outputfile.Write(richTextBox1.Text); //this is where the error occures and it throws the error of access denyed
                outputfile.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion about what to do I looked around on google for a solution but it seemed most did not work and some others I did not understand.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?  What did you look at that you didn't understand?  It helps no one if we provide solutions you've already rejected, or offer assistance that you don't understand.  Help us help you.

Comment: Aside from the fact that an exception would make the execution not call `Close` (which is why we would usually use `using`)… Nothing evident. Perhaps you only have read access, or perhaps the file is being kept open (perhaps by an unrelated program, or not, see if a reboot fixes it). Given that you are using `ReadAllText` why not use `WriteAllText`? - Do you have more details on the exception?

Comment: This code is quite crazy. You read all the file into a string, and then you loop through that string char by char, appending each char onto the end of another string that you then show in a rich text box. Do you have any idea of how many potentially million useless/wasted memory copy operations that entails? It doesn't even have any end effect; it just laboriously builds a string that is the same thing you already have

Comment: What is the value of locsave at the time you attempt to save?

Comment: … Let alone the fact that this is a class that deals with UI and the file system, which goes against separation of concerns, if not also against single responsibility principle. But let us stay at the problem at hand. Why access denied? It is not evident why.

Comment: also the reason I read the file and then loop through it is because when I read the file it for some reason turned it into an array and it had the error cannot convert string[] to string so I looped through it with string but it gave error cannot convert char[] to string so I had to loop though it character by character but I do agree it's not the best way.

Comment: Writealltext throws the same error.

Comment: @Theraot the value was c:/users/user1/desktop/test.txt

Comment: Seems to work in python but not this I'm guessing it's my .net version as I am on a old windows 10 pc but still I don't want to rewrite my entire program.

Comment: "for some reason turned it into an array and it had the error cannot convert string[] to string" Are you sure you didn't use `ReadAllLines` or `FileNames` by accident? - Well, if python, on the same machine, by the same user can do it… Let us assume that .NET version has something wrong. So let us have the standard library do less work instead of more. Try opening the file for write access with `File.Open` which gives you a `stream`, use `System.Text.Encoding` to get a `byte[]` with `GetBytes` from the `string`, and write that to the `stream`.

Comment: @Theraot GetBytes? my program does not know what it is and neither do I pls elaborate.

Comment: There are various classes that inherit from `Encoding`, including `Encoding.ASCII` and `Encoding.UTF8`. And they have a `GetBytes` method. So you do something along these lines: `using var file = System.IO.File.Open(...); var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Text); file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`

Comment: @Theraot Works thank you!